# Set Title in View in mvvmcross 5.1

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Good afternoon.

I was using Xamarin and MVVMCROSS version 5.0 to create multiple tabs and navigate them between them.
In my code i have a Root page that directs to the pages:

```
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public sealed partial class RootView : MvxTabBarViewController<RootViewModel>
{
    private bool _isPresentedFirstTime = true;

    public RootView()
    {
        // ViewDidLoad();
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        if (ViewModel != null && _isPresentedFirstTime)
        {
            _isPresentedFirstTime = false;

            ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModels();
        }

        //Alterando o BackGround da tabBar
        this.TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(237, 146, 4, 1);
        this.TabBar.Translucent = false;
        //this.TabBar.Opaque = false;
        //Cor do ícone antes de selecionado
        this.TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.White;
        //Cor do ícone após seleção
        this.TabBar.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Black;

        //Setando imagem antes e depois da seleção
        this.TabBar.Items[4].Image = UIImage.FromBundle("valdemarMenuBar.png").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
        this.TabBar.Items[4].SelectedImage = UIImage.FromBundle("valdemarMenuBar.png").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
    }
```

...

In each of the Views I set the Titles of the navigations bars according to the example below:

```
    [MvxTabPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true, TabIconName = "newOrder", TabName = "Novo Pedido")]
public partial class NewOrder2ViewController : BaseScrollViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        if (ViewModel == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Title = "Novo Pedido";

        ...
```

When I upgraded to version 5.1.1 of MVVMCROSS this functionality has stopped.
Can anyone help me about what happened.
I did not find anything in the documentation for this new version of MVVMCROSS.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about what are you asking here. So the problem is that you are setting the Title for the Tab here: `Title = "Novo Pedido";` and it just doesn't work, right?

Comment: In "Title = 'New Order'", this is where I defined the UINavigationBar title, which is not working. The title of the Tab I define in: [MvxTabPresentation (WrapInNavigationController = true, TabIconName = "newOrder", TabName = "New Order")]

Comment: You're using two NavigationControllers there, is that intended? My suspicion is the NavigationBar you're setting the title to, is behind the other one

Comment: I still can not understand the behavior ...
So I went back to version 5.0.6, where, with this code I have the perfect title in my NavigationBar.

Comment: @nmilcoff Apparently it's even creating a new NavigationBar and this has disrupted every structure I have in my code.
What I did was delete everything and now I will start over.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this strange behavior because you have two UINavigationControllers ovelapped on each tab, one over the other (this is because your TabBarViewController is wrapped in a navigation controller).

In order to fix it, you just need to change the value of the attribute property:

```
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = false)]
public sealed partial class RootView : MvxTabBarViewController<RootViewModel>
{
    //...
}
```